# Position input field outside canvas in Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use Google Map API for web.

The example of "[Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)" is what I need and it serves me well.

But I need that search field (input field) to be placed outside the map canvas.

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't saw these lines:

```
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(input);
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);
```

Removed these and was able to place where i want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, by *overriding the CSS of the search text fields.*  On inspecting I found by overriding the class **`.controls`** you can place it wherever you need.

Comment: I tried but its not working. when given new margins it diapers

Answer (score 0):

Removing `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(input);` will allow you to place your input field outside of map area.